# Parsing Binary Data in C

Tags: c++, c, parsing

I have a custom binary protocol and binary spec for a message. The binary protocol adds some headers to each message. The message is relatively large and contains near about 50 different fields. My requirement is to parse only 2 fields from the binary message in c or c++ with gcc compiler on linux 2.6.x.

One developer created a class that represents headers and another c++ class that represents the message. On receipt of the message, he simply uses static_cast on the byte payload to get back a message class. Once he gets the message object class, he simply uses pointerToMessage.getFieldName() to get the data.

A correction to the above paragraph. the developer created a struct, not a class for the message. The struct uses gcc's __attribute__((__packed__ )).

My question is that would using static_cast result in entire message getting parsed Or does parsing happens on access time, for example, at pointerToStruct.fieldName ?
Also, he timed the 2 operations and found that it takes virtually no time to do static_cast, where it takes about 120 mircoseconds to access the field via pointerToStruct.fieldName. Why would access to a field take long?

Comment: Why would static_cast perform parsing?

Comment: I apologize, as i am not c++ developer and the person who coded is unavailable. Thus the above question. So is it true then that parsing happens at access time?

Comment: @Jimm : Nothing you have described so far involves parsing at all.

Comment: Message parsing must happen in getFieldName() - but it looks strange to me, also if I understand correctly static_cast usage requires constant length of headers - or at least its length must be known somehow.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is that would using static_cast result in entire message getting parsed

No. The static_cast only tells the compiler that the memory contents pointed to by the pointer being cast should be treated as if it was containing data in the format that you cast to. If the data is not in that format, you will most likely get garbage out.

If you are 100% certain that the incoming buffer contains the correct data for the type being cast too, this is an efficient way of accessing the data. But since you talk about messages and a protocol I would duble check that things like endianness, alignment, padding and wordsize on the systems communicating will not get in the way.

> Also, he timed the 2 operations and found that it takes virtually no time to do static_cast, where it takes about 120 mircoseconds to access the field via pointerToMessage.getFieldName(). Why would access to a field take long?

Probably because tha cast realy doesn't do very much, in essence it just creates a pointer with the given type to the memory address you give it. The real access happens when you try to read the contents of the message.